# receiver.payable

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, payable

Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.1

```
pragma solidity v0.5.0;


contract ApprovalContracts { 

  address public sender;   
  address public receiver; 
  address public approver = 0xc7780C9521C2C2abED69f0D65BEbF9794C55ae94;  

  function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {  

    require(msg.value >0); 
    sender = msg.sender; 
    receiver = _receiver;
  }

  function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) { 
    return(approver);
  }

  function approve() external { 
    require(msg.sender == approver); 
    receiver.payable(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

> receiver.payable(address(this).balance); <------ transfer doesn't
>   exist in the new version

I keep getting an error, which is points payable.

> ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'payable'
>   receiver.payable(address(this).balance);

Not sure what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I fiddled with this in Remix to make sure the solution compiles.

The immediate issue is Solidity 0.5.0 introduces a new type, `address payable` and removes the transfer and send methods from `address`. To work with `payable` addresses, cast variables as `address payable`.

Here:
`address payable public receiver;`

and also here:
`function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable {`

It looks like `receiver.payable` was a guess to try to resolve the error. You probably want:

`receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);`

The compiler wasn't happy with the `v` in the pragma. When it compiled, it looked like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract ApprovalContracts { 

  address public sender;   
  address payable public receiver; 
  address public approver = 0xc7780C9521C2C2abED69f0D65BEbF9794C55ae94;  

  function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable {  

    require(msg.value >0); 
    sender = msg.sender; 
    receiver = _receiver;
  }

  function viewApprover() external view returns(address) { 
    return approver;
  }

  function approve() external { 
    require(msg.sender == approver); 
    receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you! I thought that payable was a replacement for transfer method.

Comment: Awesome. If the answer was helpful, please upvote and accept. Thanks.